# How to improve my FindDuplicate classic algorithm

Tags: c#, loops

I have classic find duplicate algorithm like this:

```
int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine();
            List<int> tempArr = new List<int>();
            List<int> array = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("input number {0}: ", i + 1);
                tempArr.Add(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
            }
            tempArr.Sort();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++)
                {
                    if (tempArr[i] == tempArr[j])
                    {
                        array.Add(tempArr[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Everything work's okay, but if i have just **two duplicate numbers** like (1,**2,2**,3,4,5) how can i add them both to `List<int> **array**` with one clean shot at the loop ?

Comment: you can use Linq Distinct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of lists you could use some kind of data structure that have a better search capability (hash tables or binary trees, for example). Even if you have just one duplicate, the problem is that you need to check if you have already added the element in the list, so the key operation in your algorithm is the search. The faster you perform the search, the faster the algorithm will be. Using binary search, which is the fastest way to search, you get O(nlogn) (you perform n searches of O(logn)).

An even better way to do this is to have some kind of array that has the same size as your input range and "tick" each value that you already have. This search runs in constant time, but gets inefficient if you have a large range of input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use distinct:

```
array = tempArr.Distinct().ToList();
```

`Distinct` isn't in linear time, if that's what you're looking for ("one clean shot"). If you know more about the input you might be able to find a way to do this in linear time. For example, if you know if the integers you take are in a certain range.

Comment: My goal is to add them both to the array so it will look like this: array = {2,2}, if i use distinct it will add only one of the duplicate numbers without repeating.

Answer (score 0):

To *extract* all the duplicates you can use *Linq*:

```
   List<int> tempList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

   // array == [2, 2]
   List<int> array = tempList
     .GroupBy(x => x)
     .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
     .SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Repeat(x.Key, x.Count()))
     .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, but i should do it with linear data structures. Your answer works perfect.